# Rotating layer around center 64 times by 5,625 degrees

Tags: adobe-photoshop

so i would like to have a script that rotates a layer 64 time by 5.625 degrees but every time before it rotates, it resets the layer to its original state(as rotating from the previus loses quality) so have it rotate by x+5.625.

I would like to save each image separately.

Comment: Why would it be any different from rotating 64*5625? Or is it 5.625? Remenber in english locales comma is a thousands separator which makes it unclear

Comment: i want it revert to its original state before rotating again to the next position. yes i mean 5.625

Comment: undo? Anyway its not clear in your question you want copies or not.

Comment: If you use a Smart Object, you won't loose quality from each rotation.

Comment: Use smart objects is another possibility

Comment: ok let rephrase it i need to have an automatic action/script that rotates an object 64 times by 5.625 degrees and each time it rotates its saves it as png with name+1 so for example F22_0000,F22_0001...F22_0063

Comment: sorry for not being specific

Comment: I'd use Illustrator for this - it's a simple 20 second thing with the Effect Menu -- unless there's some reason you *must* have raster content.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have expanded your question to explain what you want, the question is entirely different. Before it was a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) please avoid that.

Do this:

1. Make the image into a smart layer
2. open timeline and create video timeline

   - Go to **timeline hamburger menu -> panel options** and set the time format to frames
   - Go to frame 64 (first frame is 0 but we will skip the last frame when expoting) then choose  **timeline hamburger menu -> move and trim -> trim end of playhead**
3. Go to frame 0

   - click on the arrow next to layer in timeline.
   - click on transform, this enables transform of video layer
4. go to frame 31

   - trasform your layer 180 degrees (hit ctrl+t) then enter
5. go to frame 64

   - trasform your layer 180 degrees agaibn (hit ctrl+t) then enter
6. grab the timeline subsectioning tab and move it one frame back ignoring frame 64
7. Save animation out as image sequence by choosing **timeline hamburger menu -> Render video**.

   - Chose Photoshop image sequence in the type dropdown (it has no name so it might read media encoder)
   - fill in filename, location, naming conventions and render

Done

Comment: ok i will try that. yes after each rotation i want to save it as png sorry wasnt clear

Answer (score 0):

Things like this are super easy to do with the [ScriptingListener](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html#ScriptingListenerplugin) plugin — takes literally a minute or two.

So I have an image with a layer (as a smart object) that I want to rotate:

[image]

I rotate the layer the way I want: exact numbers aren't important now. And then save it as a `.png`

[image]

ScriptingListener will generate a `.log` file on the desktop. There's some garbage but I know I need 2 things: a transform and a save. So I look for a block with some numbers and a block with a save path. Here are they:

```js
// =======================================================
var idTrnf = charIDToTypeID( "Trnf" );
    var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID( "FTcs" );
    var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID( "QCSt" );
    var idQcsi = charIDToTypeID( "Qcsi" );
    desc12.putEnumerated( idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsi );
    var idPstn = charIDToTypeID( "Pstn" );
        var desc13 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc13.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, 251.985380 );
        var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc13.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, 284.023392 );
    var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );
    desc12.putObject( idPstn, idPnt, desc13 );
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
        var desc14 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc14.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, 0.000000 );
        var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc14.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, -0.000000 );
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
    desc12.putObject( idOfst, idOfst, desc14 );
    var idAngl = charIDToTypeID( "Angl" );
    var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
    desc12.putUnitDouble( idAngl, idAng, 7.740591 );
executeAction( idTrnf, desc12, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idsave = charIDToTypeID( "save" );
    var desc21 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idAs = charIDToTypeID( "As  " );
        var desc22 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idMthd = charIDToTypeID( "Mthd" );
        var idPNGMethod = stringIDToTypeID( "PNGMethod" );
        var idquick = stringIDToTypeID( "quick" );
        desc22.putEnumerated( idMthd, idPNGMethod, idquick );
        var idPGIT = charIDToTypeID( "PGIT" );
        var idPGIT = charIDToTypeID( "PGIT" );
        var idPGIN = charIDToTypeID( "PGIN" );
        desc22.putEnumerated( idPGIT, idPGIT, idPGIN );
        var idPNGf = charIDToTypeID( "PNGf" );
        var idPNGf = charIDToTypeID( "PNGf" );
        var idPGAd = charIDToTypeID( "PGAd" );
        desc22.putEnumerated( idPNGf, idPNGf, idPGAd );
        var idCmpr = charIDToTypeID( "Cmpr" );
        desc22.putInteger( idCmpr, 6 );
    var idPNGF = charIDToTypeID( "PNGF" );
    desc21.putObject( idAs, idPNGF, desc22 );
    var idIn = charIDToTypeID( "In  " );
    desc21.putPath( idIn, new File( "E:\\temp\\del\\test\\01.png" ) );
    var idDocI = charIDToTypeID( "DocI" );
    desc21.putInteger( idDocI, 821 );
    var idCpy = charIDToTypeID( "Cpy " );
    desc21.putBoolean( idCpy, true );
    var idsaveStage = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStage" );
    var idsaveStageType = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStageType" );
    var idsaveBegin = stringIDToTypeID( "saveBegin" );
    desc21.putEnumerated( idsaveStage, idsaveStageType, idsaveBegin );
executeAction( idsave, desc21, DialogModes.NO );
```

Now it's a matter of converting this to a function. Final script and result:

[image]

```js
var i;
var copies = 64;
var angle = 360 / copies;

for (i = 0; i < copies; i++) {
    rotate(angle, i)
}

function rotate(angle, i)
{
  // =======================================================
  var idTrnf = charIDToTypeID("Trnf");
  var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID("FTcs");
  var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID("QCSt");
  var idQcsi = charIDToTypeID("Qcsi");
  desc12.putEnumerated(idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsi);
  var idPstn = charIDToTypeID("Pstn");
  var desc13 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID("Hrzn");
  var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
  desc13.putUnitDouble(idHrzn, idPxl, 251.985380);
  var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID("Vrtc");
  var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
  desc13.putUnitDouble(idVrtc, idPxl, 284.023392);
  var idPnt = charIDToTypeID("Pnt ");
  desc12.putObject(idPstn, idPnt, desc13);
  var idOfst = charIDToTypeID("Ofst");
  var desc14 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID("Hrzn");
  var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
  desc14.putUnitDouble(idHrzn, idPxl, 0.000000);
  var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID("Vrtc");
  var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
  desc14.putUnitDouble(idVrtc, idPxl, -0.000000);
  var idOfst = charIDToTypeID("Ofst");
  desc12.putObject(idOfst, idOfst, desc14);
  var idAngl = charIDToTypeID("Angl");
  var idAng = charIDToTypeID("#Ang");
  desc12.putUnitDouble(idAngl, idAng, angle);
  executeAction(idTrnf, desc12, DialogModes.NO);

  // =======================================================
  var idsave = charIDToTypeID("save");
  var desc21 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idAs = charIDToTypeID("As  ");
  var desc22 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idMthd = charIDToTypeID("Mthd");
  var idPNGMethod = stringIDToTypeID("PNGMethod");
  var idquick = stringIDToTypeID("quick");
  desc22.putEnumerated(idMthd, idPNGMethod, idquick);
  var idPGIT = charIDToTypeID("PGIT");
  var idPGIT = charIDToTypeID("PGIT");
  var idPGIN = charIDToTypeID("PGIN");
  desc22.putEnumerated(idPGIT, idPGIT, idPGIN);
  var idPNGf = charIDToTypeID("PNGf");
  var idPNGf = charIDToTypeID("PNGf");
  var idPGAd = charIDToTypeID("PGAd");
  desc22.putEnumerated(idPNGf, idPNGf, idPGAd);
  var idCmpr = charIDToTypeID("Cmpr");
  desc22.putInteger(idCmpr, 6);
  var idPNGF = charIDToTypeID("PNGF");
  desc21.putObject(idAs, idPNGF, desc22);
  var idIn = charIDToTypeID("In  ");
  desc21.putPath(idIn, new File("E:\\temp\\del\\test\\F22_"+pad(i,4)+".png"));
  var idDocI = charIDToTypeID("DocI");
  desc21.putInteger(idDocI, 821);
  var idCpy = charIDToTypeID("Cpy ");
  desc21.putBoolean(idCpy, true);
  var idsaveStage = stringIDToTypeID("saveStage");
  var idsaveStageType = stringIDToTypeID("saveStageType");
  var idsaveBegin = stringIDToTypeID("saveBegin");
  desc21.putEnumerated(idsaveStage, idsaveStageType, idsaveBegin);
  executeAction(idsave, desc21, DialogModes.NO);

}

function pad(n, width, z)
{
  z = z || '0';
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}
```

Comment: Yes but its still an animation so better animate, easier to edit. But also if one bothers to read the api docs youll find it can be done with much less code.

Comment: @joojaa I agree, but why not to suggest a different approach? That also could be a way for resolving more complex tasks later on for someone.

Comment: Ues, but not really easy to extend.

Comment: @joojaa Why? I think it's easy extendable when you know the principle — finding the parts you need in the AM log and some very basic JS.

Comment: Part of the reason to write code is to make your process understandable. This aint it. But yeah its easy do though. You could have recorded a action and looped that would have been even easier.

Comment: @joojaa well, AM gets understandable with experience. Anyway, I guess OP would know what's _better_ for him: as I mentioned I wanted to show a different approach that I personally prefer.